# In python, I want to delete the last letter from the string value in the data and convert it to a number

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgJyW.png)

> I want to remove the + sign at the end of the Installs column in the image and convert it to a number.

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import os
 data = pd.read_csv("../input/googleplaystore.csv")
 data.info()
 data.head(10)
 if data.Installs.endswith("+"):
    data.Installs =data.Installs[:-1]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you provide sample input and expected output for that input?

Comment: Hi unfortunately I do not have a sample output for this, but I shared the sample data photo my goal is to remove the last letter + Installs column of the column to convert to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a pandas `Series` like this:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> installs = pd.Series(["10,000+", "500,000+", "5,000,000+"])

>>> print(installs)
0       10,000+
1      500,000+
2    5,000,000+
dtype: object
```

Use the pandas Accessor object [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) to replace all occurences of `"+"` and `","` with an empty string. **This is far more robust compared to just removing the last character.**

```py
>>> installs = installs.str.replace("+", "")
>>> installs = installs.str.replace(",", "")
```

To apply numeric functions afterwards (e.g. `sum`) change the datatype to `int`.

```py
>>> installs = installs.astype(int)
```

With [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) we can make it even clearer. (The brackets `[]` define a set of characters to be replaced.)

```py
>>> installs = installs.str.replace("[+,]", "").astype(int)
```

```py
>>> print(installs)
0      10000
1     500000
2    5000000
dtype: int64
```

#### Conclusions:

This should solve your problem:

```py
data.Installs = data.Installs.str.replace("[+,]", "").astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer GeeksForGeeks for this
**https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-last-character-in-list-of-strings/**

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# remove last character from list of strings 
# using map() + lambda 

# initializing list 
test_list = ['Manjeets'] 

# printing original list 
print("The original list : " + str(test_list)) 

# using map() + lambda 
# remove last character from list of strings 
res = list(map(lambda i: i[ : -1], test_list)) 

# printing result 
print("The list after removing last characters : " + str(res)) 
``
**Output**
**The original list : ['Manjeets']
The list after removing last characters : ['Manjeet']**
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
data = pd.read_csv("../input/googleplaystore.csv")
data.info()
data.head(10)
if data.Installs.endswith("+"):
   data.Installs = data.Installs[:-1].astype(int) #Assuming of course that it's a numpy/pandas column or something.
```

Comment: When try this AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: O yeah, you need to use, data.Installs.str.endswith(search) to get rows that end with your search requirement. Then actually the whole logic changes. It's tough to debug with half information bro.